# "Had to" vs. "must" for requirement in the past

Tags: word-choice, past-tense, verb-usage

I know that "have to" can mean "must" and that "must" can be used in the past, but in the below sentence I don't understand why "had to" is the correct answer.

> When I was going to university, I _____ find a part time job to earn some
>   pocket money, because my family was not rich.
>
> 1. had to
> 2. must
> 3. should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In context of obligation/necessity (as in your sentence), *must* isn't usually used to talk about the past: instead, it's paraphrased with the past form of the periphrastic modal *have to*, which is *had to*.

It would be wrong to say that *had to* is the *past form* of *must* – since *must* doesn't have a true past form – but for all intents and purposes, you can think of it as such; i.e., whenever you wish to express the meaning of *must* when you're talking about obligation/necessity in the past, use *had to* (or *have had to*, which is blessed with the [perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) aspect; e.g., *He **has had to** visit the ER several times*).

Answer (score 1):

As the modal verb *must* cannot be conjugated as a "normal" verb can, other verbal forms need to be used in order for past or future actions to be verbalized.

Thus:

> I **must** do my homework.

(*Must* is used for a present action)

> I **had to** do my homework.

(*Had to* replaces *must* when referring to a past action)

> I **will have to** do my homework.

(*Will have to* replaces *must* when referring to a future action)

So, in the context of your sentence, the verbal replacement that you need to use in lieu of *must*, according to the time frame in which the meaning of *must* takes place, is *had to*.